# Shopify white bar which i cant remove

Tags: css, shopify

I've been trying to remove this white bar that show between two sections on Shopify. The code i see that impact this is:

```css
.section + .section {
  margin-top: var(--spacing-sections-mobile);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  .section + .section {
    margin-top: var(--spacing-sections-desktop);
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPXo8.png)

Can someone please help me understand how to remove this white bar?

Thanks

Comment: which theme you are using?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're with some 2.0 theme, try something like this:

```
body .section + .section {
 margin-top:0; 
 margin-bottom:0;
}
```